# Scrum/Agile for web sites

Tags: web-applications, scrum

If scrum unit of measure is the user story:

How do you factor in non-functional requirements? Of more interest to me, is infrastructure?

In the framework of my choice about 50% of the time is spent configuring modules, writing templates, etc...

How do these requirements work in scrum? How do I word a user story:

As *any user* under *all conditions* I expect output to be bold?!? :)

I would guess than each of the types of requirements in a complex web app would be planned and executed differently...

Any experience or opinions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software development methodologies rather than low-level programming

Comment: Get Atlassian JIRA. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating user stories with tasks.

The user story is the feature to be developed. The story points used to estimate it represent one unit of measure, a broad means of comparison of estimated effort among features. However, when it comes time to develop a feature, it gets broken down into tasks at the Sprint Planning Meeting. You use hours to estimate the task durations in a Sprint Backlog.

So the user story is not a unit of measure. It is a feature--comprised of all the tasks that go into developing that feature. These tasks include configuring modules, writing templates, writing code, writing unit tests, testing the features, etc. Whatever is in the Definition of Done.

You might have a story like "As a user, I want to see the ticker symbols and prices for my stocks emphasized so I can distinguish them from the others." That's a feature defined in user terms to describe what the user wants.

The example you gave is a task, so you don't turn it into a story. However, it makes perfect sense as one of the tasks that need to be performed in order to develop that story.

So basically, the user story represents a full feature a user wants to execute on the application, and that is estimated in story points (and possibly re-estimated throughout the project). When it comes time for the sprint where that user story will be developed, it gets broken down into the necessary tasks, which are estimated in hours.

Hope that helps.